# Map a nested spread onto a spread

Tags: typescript, spread-syntax

I have an array with Persons and want to spread new entries. But I do not have Persons to spread, just lastNames. How do I solve this?

```ts
type Person = {
   name: string,
   lastName: string,
   age: number
}

function MyComponent() {
   const [persons, setPersons] = useState<Person[]>([])

   function addNewPersons(lastName: string[]): void {
      setPersons((prevState: Person[]) => [
         ...prevState,
         // spread lastName[] onto Person[]
      ]);
   }

   return <></>;
}
```

Comment: So you want to update the last names of everyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly something like this...

```js
type Person = {
  name?: string;
  lastName: string;
  age?: number;
};

function MyComponent() {
  const [persons, setPersons] = useState<Person[]>([]);

  function addNewPersons(lastNames: string[]) {
    const newPersons: Person[] = lastNames.map((lastName) => ({
      lastName,
    }));
    setPersons((prevPersons: Person[]) => [...prevPersons, ...newPersons]);
  }

  return <></>;
}
```